# Datatable paging is not working when I use moment.js

Tags: datatables, momentjs

I use moment.js to sorting date in Datatable.It's working.
But Paging function of Datatable is not working.
My code is.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'); 
     $('.cashCollectorTable').DataTable({
          paging: true, 
     });
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Now with nested cargo `readys()` :) There is *nothing* with momentjs that at any time nor theoretically could conflict with DataTables paging feature. BTW: `paging` is true by default. Try narrow your code down to the absolute minimum to isolate the problem - guess you have more than the shown above.

Comment: I have other javascript for button click. One more thing is I have to use double  $(document).ready(function() for  $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'); . If I don't use moment date sorting function is not work. Do I need to use like that?

Comment: can you try replicate the problem in a fiddle? Here is a starting point **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1000/** moment translate the content of your timestamps, it does not work without moment because the format described not is a "valid" date format, i.e `Date.parse()` will return NaN.